# How to print the output of `execvp` in terminal?

Tags: c, file, execvp

I am reading a file line by line, and I am hoping to execute that lines using `execvp`. However, when I use the following codes, it does not print out anything. (The codes successfully compile and run, but there is no output in terminal.) How can I print the output of `execvp` in terminal?

```
//open file and read line by line
FILE * fp;
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;

//open file (read only)
fp = fopen(cd, "r");

//exit if fail to open file
if (fp == NULL)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//read line by line
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) 
{
  //execute the line
  char * cmd[] = {line, NULL};
  execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
}
```

Comment: 1. You never set `command`. 2. You need to know that `execvp` does not return if it succeeds.

Comment: Thank you for the catch! I tested with so many different codes that I forgot to change it back to `line`. I edited my question now.